# How I can insert same values with different date on single insertion?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I want to write script function to insert  multiple same query.

I want to insert multiple same records to table for example I want to insert it ten times but with different date for each insertion .

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (name,age,address,phone,dat) 
 VALUES ('$name','$email','$address','$phone','$date')")
 or die (mysql_ereror());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("
INSERT INTO `table` (name,age,address,phone,dat) 
VALUES 
('$name','$email','$address','$phone','$date1'),
('$name','$email','$address','$phone','$date2'),
('$name','$email','$address','$phone','$date3'),
('$name','$email','$address','$phone','$date4'),
('$name','$email','$address','$phone','$dateN')
")
 or die (mysql_ereror());
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.but the think which i want is not like that.         INSERT INTO `table` (name,age,address,phone,dat) 
VALUES 
('$name','$email','$address','$phone','$date'),...in my interface i have two dates option from_date and to_date...12/09/2015 to 20/09/2015...sir if you check there difference is 8 ....so i want 8 same entries but with different date..how it can be possible with the help of loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
    $date1 = date_create("2015-09-12");
    $date2 = date_create("2015-09-20");
    $interval = date_diff($date1, $date2);
    $dateDifference = $interval->format('%a days');
    $query = "INSERT INTO `table` (name,age,address,phone,dat) VALUES ";
    for($i=0; $i<=$dateDifference;$i++)
    {
        $date = date_create("2015-09-12");
        $newDate = date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string($i.' days'));
        $query .= "('$name', '$age', '$address', '$phone', '".date_format($newDate, 'd-m-Y')."'), ";
    }
    $query = substr($query, 0, -2);
    mysql_query($query);
```